# How to notify users when new app version is available in Apache Cordova iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

We have an Apache Cordova iOS app built with simple HTML/JS/CSS. We are not using any framework. What is the best way to notify users when new version of the application is available in the app store. Is there any plugin that makes this flow easier?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of

1. Use push notifications - more than one Cordova plugin available.
2. Have an endpoint on your server that the application checks, either on startup or on interval, that returns latest version. You compare the installed version with the latest and if not the same popup "update avail"

"2" might be easier to implement, but "1" gives you the option to use push for other purposes which can be useful.

Comment: I've successfully implemented (2) in the past you just make an Ajax call to a simple service that returns the latest version of the app and compare it with the running one then pop a dialog with an app store / google play link if latest version > running version.